viewpoint option for top left corner
To following up this SO answer.
I would like to use viewport to show top left corner part of pdf image. but by default the viewport origin is from bottom left.
example below wish to view (0,0,100,100) rectangle from top left corner, but actually it's a rectangle at bottom left.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
   \includegraphics[width=500pt,viewport=0 0 100 100,clip]{example-image-a}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Any option to change origin to top left corner?
One possible solution to use savebox to get the height, then do some math to get the crop area, but below code not work。
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\def\fname{example-image-a}
\newsavebox{\graph}\savebox{\graph}{\includegraphics[width=500pt]{\fname}}
\newlength\gh\setlength\gh{\heightof{\usebox\graph}}
\newlength\gw\setlength\gw{\widthof{\usebox\graph}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\typeout{\the\gw}
\typeout{\the\gh}
  \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {%
   \includegraphics[width=500pt,viewport={0} {\gh-100pt} {100pt} {\gh},clip]{example-image-a}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


please link relevant previous questions you've asked to avoid people duplicating efforts. you can see the options available in graphicx documentation, which includes a description of what these various options mean/do. as I said before, the origin is the origin specified in the image file. you can parametise one of the answers to your earlier question so the origin seems to be lower left in some custom command, but you can't alter what is given by the image (except in the image file, obviously).

viewport doesn't expect braced components. It expects e.g. viewport=0 0 72 72 or whatever. that's one reason why my answer didn't use \includegraphics directly but a wrapper which could pass the argument on in an appropriate form.

Scaling is applied at the end, so all your measurements are off.
I suggest to set the material (\includegraphics or whatever) and set the parameters.
In the four arguments for \viewport you can use \height, \width and also \depth.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\viewport}{mmmmm}
 {% #1=llx, #2=lly, #3=urx, #4=ury, #5=material
  \lucky_viewport:nnnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
 }

\box_new:N \l__lucky_viewport_object_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lucky_viewport:nnnnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__lucky_viewport_object_box {#5}
  \cs_set:Npe \height { \dim_eval:n { \box_ht:N \l__lucky_viewport_object_box } }
  \cs_set:Npe \depth { \dim_eval:n { \box_dp:N \l__lucky_viewport_object_box } }
  \cs_set:Npe \width { \dim_eval:n { \box_wd:N \l__lucky_viewport_object_box } }
  \box_set_viewport:Nnnnn \l__lucky_viewport_object_box {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4}
  \box_set_clipped:N \l__lucky_viewport_object_box
  \box_use:N \l__lucky_viewport_object_box
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\viewport{0pt}{\height-100pt}{100pt}{\height}
  {\includegraphics[width=500pt]{example-image-a}}

\end{document}


